# Swift - Horizontal Bar under selected button

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to add a white horizontal bar under my selected button on the menu. Just like YouTube app. [This is my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oncjg.png)

[Abd this is Youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFeog.png)

I searched for info but i couldnt find anything about this. And this is my code. Thanks

```
import UIKit

class TabViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    var rifleViewController: UIViewController!
    var pistolViewController: UIViewController!
    var shotgunViewController: UIViewController!
    var smgsViewController: UIViewController!
    var sniperViewController: UIViewController!

    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]!
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        rifleViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rifles")
        sniperViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "snipers")
        smgsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "smgss")
        shotgunViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shotguns")
        pistolViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pistols")
        viewControllers = [rifleViewController,
                           pistolViewController,
                           shotgunViewController,
                           smgsViewController,
                           sniperViewController]

        buttons[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
        didPressTab(buttons[selectedIndex])


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let previousIndex = selectedIndex

        selectedIndex = sender.tag

        buttons[previousIndex].isSelected = false
        let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]

        previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        sender.isSelected = true

        let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

        addChildViewController(vc)

        vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with the help of a simple animation. 
In my example - App, I added a view at the top of the screen in the storyboard and put four buttons on top of it. Then i connected the buttons to the function called "buttonTapped" (important: you need to include the sender here). 
The code is fairly simple:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
var movingView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 55, width: screenWidth / 4, height: 5))
    movingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white   //if backgroundView's color is black
    backgroundView.addSubview(movingView)
}


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let newx = sender.frame.origin.x

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newx
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No, this is a plain UIView with black background. I placed the Buttons inside  this view.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did it and looks great!!

Comment: Yes i got it. Sorry about that. It was a stupid question :)

Comment: Hey man! I have a question. We give 'movingView' a 'y' value,  but when i run my app at different devices with different screen sizes it always appears at 'y: 55' and i have a problem. Is there anyway to add a constraint to it so it always shows up at the bottom of the view

Comment: Cant you do something like 
let yPos = backgroundView.bounds.size.height - 5
and then

Comment: movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yPos, width: screenWidth / 4, height: 5))

Comment: I solved my problem with this line      movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: backgroundView.frame.maxY - 5, width: screenWidth / 5, height: 10))    Thank you for your answer